# neighborhood of elements in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to check whether the difference between elements of the neighborhood of an element in a matrix are greater than some tolerance value and if they are, then give the value of 1 at the same index of the element in the neighborhood in a new matrix. Somehow I always end up with all ones in the new matrix, which is wrong. This is my code. Also, I get the matrix by converting a picture to a matrix.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided


imo = Image.open("/home/gauss/Pictures/images.jpg")


matrix_pic = np.array(imo.convert('L')).astype(float)
dim = matrix_pic.shape


# start 1 step out of the outer borders of the matrix


def binary_edges(pic_mat , tolerance):  
    dim = pic_mat.shape
    binary_mat = np.zeros((dim[0],dim[1]))
    for i in range(1  , dim[0]-1):
        for j in range(1  ,dim[1]-1):
            center = pic_mat[i,j]
            if (abs(pic_mat[i+1,j] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i+1,j] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i,j+1] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i,j+1] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i+1,j+1] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i+1,j+1] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i-1,j] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i-1,j] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i,j-1] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i,j-1] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i-1,j-1] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i-1,j-1] = 1
    return binary_mat       

myarray = binary_edges(matrix_pic, 60)
im = Image.fromarray(myarray)
im.show()
```

Comment: It looks good to me: try printing myarray, and printing matrix_pic (to see typical sizes of numbers).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problem with copying to the new matrix. Now in the new matrix of myarray, I have elements of one and zero, and I am trying to convert it to a pic using the PIL module, do you know if I am doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Not sure how I missed that this was posted many years ago, oh well, I'll leave this answer for the sake of those who follow.

Based on the comments it looks as though you may have solved one of your issues, however it seems to me that your function binary_edges is incorrect for your intended purpose in another way.

```
def binary_edges(pic_mat , tolerance):  
    dim = pic_mat.shape
    binary_mat = np.zeros((dim[0],dim[1]))
    for i in range(1  , dim[0]-1):
        for j in range(1  ,dim[1]-1):
            center = pic_mat[i,j]
            if (abs(pic_mat[i+1,j] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i+1,j] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i,j+1] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i,j+1] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i+1,j+1] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i+1,j+1] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i-1,j] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i-1,j] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i,j-1] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i,j-1] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i-1,j-1] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i-1,j-1] = 1
            #If I understand your intention correctly, then I think you're missing these two lines (notice that each element should have 8 neighbours)
            if (abs(pic_mat[i+1,j-1] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i+1,j-1] = 1
            if (abs(pic_mat[i-1,j+11] - center ) > tolerance):
                binary_mat[i-1,j+11] = 1
    return binary_mat
```

Might I suggest an alternative method which will be significantly faster for reasonably sized pic_mat matrices and in my opinion has less clutter.

```
def binary_edges_np(pic_mat, tolerance):
    dim = pic_mat.shape
    binary_mat = np.zeros((dim[0],dim[1]), dtype=bool)
    for i,j in [0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[1,-1]:
        s = pic_mat.shape
        slice1 = np.s_[max(0, 0+i):s[0]+i, max(0+j,0):s[1]+j]
        slice2 = np.s_[max(0-i,0):s[0]-i, max(0-j,0):s[1]-j]
        bool_slice = np.abs(pic_mat[slice1] - pic_mat[slice2]) > tolerance
        binary_mat[slice1] += bool_slice
        binary_mat[slice2] += bool_slice
    return binary_mat
```

As follows:

```
matrix_pic = np.random.randint(0,255, (1000,1000))
s = time.time()
a = binary_edges(matrix_pic, 60)
print("binary_edges:", time.time() - s)
s = time.time()
b = binary_edges_np(matrix_pic, 60)
print("binary_edges_np:", time.time() - s)
```

binary_edges: 5.694662809371948,
binary_edges_np: 0.01562666893005371

Furthermore, note that your original function has certainly boundary effects where elements within 2 rows/cols of the edges will not be marked properly as exceeding the threshold, I assume this was not intentional. The new method gives the correct values for the edges too:

```
print((a == b).all()) # = False
print((a[2:-2,2:-2] == b[2:-2,2:-2]).all()) # True
```